# How can a view fill a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC view and related model.

How can I fill its related model from within the view?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I think you're jumping the gun.  It's best practice to not fill a DATA model from view, filling a View Model from view is its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You POST to a controller action from your view and the model binder will populate it:

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
    // your model has been populated by what was in the form at this point
}
```

Comment: I want to add client kind of corrent context fields which are not in the form itself. Use hidden fields?

Comment: @EladBenda Yes you can use hidden fields for this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  MVC does, and it does this automatically when the form is posted back to the controller (assuming you're using model binding, and not a FormsCollection)

Comment: I want to add client kind of `corrent context` fields which are not in the form itself.

Comment: @EladBenda - I have no idea what a "corrent context fields" are.